# quickly vs cx_freeze for ubuntu application development

Tags: python, deployment, pyside, packaging

I want to use PySide and Python for application development in Ubuntu. As far as I can see, I have two options:

1. Use cx_freeze to create an executable file and other pertaining files and then go about the normal course of getting a Ubuntu application out to the world.
2. Use Quickly to package my application and all of the other useful things it can do. I *would* just go straight to this option, but I have not heard/seen anything about using Quickly with PySide.

Has anyone had this experience in my situation (PySide and Python for Ubuntu Apps)? Which one did you choose, or is there another choice I'm missing? I am looking for simplicity and effectiveness.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't just package your app into a `.deb` file? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb

Comment: Does that work for ubuntu too? (sorry I don't have a lot of experience with ubuntu)

Comment: Yep, Ubuntu uses the same package format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, thanks to [Blender's helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310668/quickly-vs-cx-freeze-for-ubuntu-application-development#comment23353975_16310668), I now know that packaging my application into a .deb file using [stdeb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb) is the best/easiest way to package my application for Ubuntu